# Functional analysis. Sequences in $l^{\infty} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $F = \{(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \in l^{\infty} : |x_n|<1 \}$. Is F open in $l^{\infty}$?

I know $l^{\infty}$ is the metric space of all sequences with the sup norm such that $\sup\{|x_n|\}<{\infty}$.

Is easy to see that $||x-y||_{\infty} \le 2$ for all $x, y \in F$. Also that if $x$ is an interior point of $F$, then for all $y \in l^{\infty}$ such that $||x-y||_{\infty}<\epsilon$ we know $|y_n|<1$, that is, it must be inside the ball around $x$ of radius  $\epsilon$. I don't think $F$ is open. In that case, for some $\textbf{x} \in F$ I need to find a $\textbf{y} \in l^{\infty}$ such that $\textbf{y} \in B(\textbf{x},\epsilon)$ but $\textbf{y} \not \in F$ for all $\epsilon>0$. I couldn't find any, nor prove that $F$ is open. Some insights?

Answer (score 3):

Take $x_n=1-2^{-n}$ for $n\in\Bbb N$, and let $\textbf{x}=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle\in F$. Fix $\epsilon>0$. For $n\in\Bbb N$ let $y_n=x_n+\frac\epsilon2$, and let $\textbf{y}=\langle y_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle\in B(\textbf{x},\epsilon)$. What happens when $n$ is large enough that $2^{-n}<\frac\epsilon2$?

Comment: Then for $n$ large enough $|y_n| = |(1-2^{-n})+\frac{\epsilon}{2}| > |(1-\frac{\epsilon}{2})+\frac{\epsilon}{2}| = 1$ so $\textbf{y} \not\in F$

Comment: @DavidCortesOspina: Yep, you’ve got it.

Comment: Just one more question. I've just notice that $\sup\{|x_n|\} = 1$, does that imply that $\textbf{x}$ belongs to $F$?

Comment: @DavidCortesOspina: It doesn’t say anything one way or the other about whether $\textbf{x}\in F$: it’s the fact that $|x_n|<1$ for each $n$ that tells us that $\textbf{x}\in F$.